# Does the "Soul Eater NOT" anime or manga have any appearances of the original Soul Eater Character?

Tags: soul-eater

Does "Soul Eater NOT" have any "Soul Eater" character appearances like Kidd, Maka or Soul?

Comment: Yes and you could have found that out by googling "Soul Eater NOT characters".

Comment: I have cleared up your question title as "original character appearances" can in fact refer to character who are original to Soul Eater NOT while it appears you are asking about character from the original series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Kidd, Maka and Soul appear in Soul Eater Not! and they interact with the students of the NOT class, for example Maka in the first episode:

> Whilst struggling to climb the large amount of steps leading up to the
>   DWMA, Tsugumi is helped out by one of the students, Maka Albarn, who
>   encourages her to reach the top […]

<sup>Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_Eater_Not!)</sup>

There are several other occasions where they interact but the show is focused on the NOT class students.